# json issue: GetFeatureInfo with raster images

Tags: raster, wms, json, getfeatureinfo

I have succesfully typed a GetFeatureInfo request with the following structure directly into my browser:

```
http://192.168.1.20/geoserver/workspace/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&CRS=CRS:84&BBOX=39.32295698174142,-8.4236378760969881,39.363077494358599,-8.3933494101086144&WIDTH=1114&HEIGHT=841&LAYERS=layer&QUERY_LAYERS=layer&FORMAT=image/png&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&FEATURE_COUNT=50&I=396&J=579
```

It returns me onto the screen:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":162}}]}
```

This image was a 8-bit jpeg.

Now, when I try to do the same over a 16-bit raster image, it does not return any value:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[]}
```

I was wondering whether the raster type is a key-fact0r on this issue.

Do I have to run the query in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

If that Geoserver is your own you can have a look at the "sfdem" demo layer. The GeoTIFF DEM file "sfdem.tif" that is used as a source it 32-bit as you can check with gdalinfo:

Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray

You can run GetFeatureInfo for this 32-bit raster image and get a response.

```
> http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sf/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml&BBOX=580470%2C4906552.851563%2C618510%2C4935157.148438&SERVICE=WMS&INFO_FORMAT=application/json&QUERY_LAYERS=sf%3Asfdem&FEATURE_COUNT=50&Layers=sf%3Asfdem&WIDTH=512&HEIGHT=385&format=image%2Fjpeg&styles=&srs=EPSG%3A26713&version=1.1.1&x=273&y=164
```

I get a result

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":1187}}]}
```

I would say that the GetFeatureInfo should work also with your 16-bit image. I can't say what goes wrong for you but I would first check that the BBOX of the query is inside the area of your 16-bit image.

Comment: Finally, it turns out that effectively 16-bit are readable. The thing is that I was trying to access via external ip, not localhost, and I didn't know that the 16-bit image was somehow blocked because there was a Data Security rule enabled and associated with that workspace. After removing that rule, in the same way the 8-bit is accessible, so the 16-bit does. Thanks for your post.